# WampServer Apache module Unable to start

Tags: php, apache, ssl, wampserver, swiftmailer

I run Swiftmailer from my local wampserver, but after I formated my pc and  wanted to setup again I get error trying to enable "LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so" . I run swiftmailer with smtp and ssl/tls support. So I needed to enable php_openssl.dll, php_smtp.dll,php_socket.dll in php.ini, everything works at this stage and until I un commented  the "LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so" line. Apache stopped starting.

How do I load The "LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so"?

Comment: Have you checked your Apache error logs? Can you share error details from log?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that something else is holding port 443 open. In a Windows command prompt check: `netstat -a` to get a list of port numbers actively being listen on. Make sure WAMP is shut down before checking.